# como soluciono el error org.jsonexception: value <br> of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray

Tags: json

hola amigos es mi primera y recién estoy empezando en estas lides de android, llevo varios días tratando de solucionar este error y buscando información a través de la web pero no hay nada que me ayude, este el código que utilizo en android.

```
private void buscar_casos (String URL){
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    et_clave.setText(jsonObject.getInt("ID"));
                    et_denuncia.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Denuncia"));
                    et_siniestro.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Siniestro"));
                    et_numsiniestro.setText(jsonObject.getInt("N_Siniestro"));
                    et_descripcion.setText(jsonObject.getString("Descripcion"));
                    et_conductor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Conductor"));
                    et_rut.setText(jsonObject.getString("Rut_Conductor"));
                    et_patente.setText(jsonObject.getString("Patente_Vehiculo"));
                    et_tercero.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Tercero"));
                    et_patenteter.setText(jsonObject.getString("Patente_Tercero"));
                    et_compania.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Compania"));
                    et_inspeccion.setText(jsonObject.getString("Inspeccion"));
                    et_nombre.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Asegurado"));
                    et_rut1.setText(jsonObject.getString("Rut_Asegurado"));
                    et_poliza.setText(jsonObject.getInt("N_Poliza"));
                    et_causa.setText(jsonObject.getString("Tipo_Seguro"));
                    et_analista.setText(jsonObject.getString("Analista"));
                    et_perdida.setText(jsonObject.getString("Perdida"));
                    et_designacion.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Designacion"));
                    et_monto.setText(jsonObject.getInt("Monto_Perdida"));
                    et_informe.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Informe"));
                    et_inspector.setText(jsonObject.getString("Inspector"));
                    et_activo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Activo"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    );
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

y este es el llamado a través del android

```
btn_buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buscar_casos("http://192.168.1.96/oficina/buscar.php?ID ="+et_registro.getText()+"");
        }
    });
```

al presionar el boton buscar me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error ahora "error org.jsonexception: value not of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray"

y este es el código que se usa en php

```
    <?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 
include ("conexion.php");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
 
    $ID = isset($_GET['ID']) ? $_GET['ID'] : '';
 
    $mysqli= new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'oficina');
    $query = "Select * From casos Where ID = '$ID'";
 
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    if ($mysqli -> affected_rows > 0){
        while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
            $casos = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
        }
    echo json_encode($casos);
    } else {
    echo "No se encontraron datos";
    }
    $result ->close();
    $mysqli ->close();
}
?>
```

como pueden ver los códigos sencillos ya que soy nuevo es estas lides, ojala que me puedan ayudar amigos ya que como mencione anteriormente llevo muchos días en esto y no se que mas hacer, y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: de dónde está saliendo el valor `<br/>`?

Comment: Ese error me pasaba muy seguido y era porque tenia alguna campo mal escrito, por lo tanto te invito a que rectifiques lo siguiente:                                        1)Revisa que los campos de la base de datos sean iguales a los de la consulta PHP                                                                                                                  2)Asegurate que en android tambien escribas los datos correctamente                 
3)Verifica con un Toast o un sout que es lo que te esta trayendo la cunsulta PHP, en la consola puedes verificar los campos nulos y no nulos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Loquillo por tu ayuda, pero ya revise todos los campos y los nombre de los campos, estuve averiguando un poco más y el <br>, se explica que no entrega un formato json sino en HTML, pero como mencione anteriormente lo probé es postmann y en la web y esta Ok no envía ningún mensaje de error.
Por otro lado se me olvido mencionar que en los registros de la tabla casos, hay dos de estos que dependiendo del caso son vacíos, es decir nulos, puede ser que ahí este el error, ya no se que pensar, llevo mas de una semana en esto y no he podido solucionarlo